# Null pointer exception from ODataApplicationInitializer in SpringBoot jar

Tags: s4sdk

I created my project by using S/4HANA SDK (spring boot archetype), now I need the functionality to provision some ODATA services so I also introduce the dependency com.sap.cloud.servicesdk.provodatav4 to my project and then create metadata file and odata service implementation class. However, after packaging my project into jar file and run it, I get null pointer exception from the class com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v4.rt.core.web.ODataApplicationInitializer. After seeing the source code of this class, it seems it use "File" object to get metadata file from classpath, but this way doesn't work in a jar file. My question is: does it mean I have to change the packaging way to "war" in order to use this SDK for odata service development? Thanks very much.

Comment: Hello Eric, if any of the answers satisfy you, please mark them as 'accepted'. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The unfortunate answer is that, as of today, the Service SDK (not the S/4HANA Cloud SDK) is only compatible with pure Tomcat environments and assumes the Servlet standard as well as surrounding mechanisms as the default mean. The reasons for this is that the Service SDK is an integral part (the runtime) of the SAP Cloud Application Programming Model which is self-contained and may not be combined with arbitrary frameworks such as Spring Boot.

Comment: In addition [this page](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/00823f91779d4d42aa29a498e0535cdf.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Philipp's answer that this is not supported, you may be able to use the [traditional deployment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) here. However, since this is likely not supported officially, I would encourage to consider an alternative approach.